# How to scale a view AND its bounds in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, scale, android-custom-view

I created a custom view and am looking to scale the view AND it's bounds. Is this possible through the layout? Or maybe something I have to change in the `CustomView`'s class?

When I used `scaleX` and `scaleY` in the layout files, the image can shrink, or grow, but ultimately the bounds stay where it's at.

Here is an example. To the left is the normal size and normal scale and to the right is the `CustomView` scaled by `0.5` in both the `x` and `y` axis.
[image]

If it helps, the `CustomView` is made by a few `ImageView` in `ConstraintLayout`. I've tried just changing `layout_width` and `layout_height` to definite values but then only some views scale accordingly while others stay big.

EDIT:

Here is the `xml` file for the `CustomView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:padding="40dp"
tools:ignore="ContentDescription">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/justiceTop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/justiceBase"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/justiceBase"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/justiceBase"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_justice_scale_top" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/justiceBase"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/justiceTop"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_justice_scale_base" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/justiceBeam"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:rotation="0"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/justiceTop"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/justiceTop"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_justice_scale_top_beam"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/leftWeightPivot"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    app:layout_constraintCircle="@id/justiceBeam"
    app:layout_constraintCircleAngle="260"
    app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="70dp"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/rightWeightPivot"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    app:layout_constraintCircle="@id/justiceBeam"
    app:layout_constraintCircleAngle="100"
    app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="70dp"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/justiceWeightLeft"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/leftWeightPivot"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/leftWeightPivot"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/leftWeightPivot"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_justice_scale_weight" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/justiceWeightRight"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/rightWeightPivot"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/rightWeightPivot"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rightWeightPivot"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_justice_scale_weight" />
```

And here's what happens if I set the `layout_width` and `layout_height` to `130dp`

[image]

Comment: Changing the width and height is what you want. Can you post the custom view layout, maybe I can help with the scaling issues you're talking about.

Comment: @Nicolas Thank you, I've added the layout file